# Some saved places are not shown on map

Tags: google-workspace, google-maps

I have saved Dune of Pilat to my custom list:

[image]

If I zoom out I see my other bookmark from the same list, but there is no Dune of Pilat mark on map.

[image]

Why some bookmarks are visible and some not from the same custom made list?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is (probably) due to a bug in Google Maps.

you just need to unhide them

also whenever you enter directions it will automatically hide your labels (all except those with star) even if they are set as unhidden and/or public

[image]

and here is how to show them during entering directions: with the mouse, if you deselect the last point that was selected as a destination, they will show up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can not see your desire location it mean it first has been added so first add tag in google map then definitely You will see it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried what everyone else has said and it helps, but, after you have tried all those things, making sure your locations are not hidden, then just select one saved location and move the sidebar/information bar aside (if on PC or Phone) and then you should be able to zoom all the way out and see all your locations!
Helps if you want to see them all at one time to show someone.
[image: Here is an example]